# Javascript: How to filter object array push from mysql query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I got an array from mysql

```
var notes = []
db.query('SELECT * FROM test WHERE working = 0')
            .on('result', function(data){
                // Push results onto the notes array
                notes.push(data)                
            }) 
            .on('end', function(){
                // Only emit notes after query has been completed
                console.log(notes)
            })

note = [ RowDataPacket { id: 12, link: 'This is a random 74 note', working: 0 },
  RowDataPacket { id: 16, link: 'This is a random 80 note', working: 0 },
  RowDataPacket { id: 44, link: 'This is a random 29 note', working: 0 } ]
```

I trying to filter some oject but it not working.

```
notes = notes.filter(function(obj) {
          return obj.id !== data.noteid;
        });
```

Its return the same array

```
note = [ RowDataPacket { id: 12, link: 'This is a random 74 note', working: 0 },
  RowDataPacket { id: 16, link: 'This is a random 80 note', working: 0 },
  RowDataPacket { id: 44, link: 'This is a random 29 note', working: 0 } ]
```

any idea?

Comment: can we see what the database is returning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this function to remove an object from an array.

```
var removeByAttr = function(arr, attr, value){
    var i = arr.length;
    while(i--){
       if( arr[i] 
           && arr[i].hasOwnProperty(attr) 
           && (arguments.length > 2 && arr[i][attr] === value ) ){ 
           arr.splice(i,1);
       }
    }
    return arr;
}

removeByAttr(notes, 'id', parseInt(data.noteid))
```

It's working fine :)